# Проблема с загрузкой страницы по хеш

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Не загружается страница, которая создана Аяксом. Мобильный сайт построен на jq mobile .

Есть страница `/#auth` без Ajax. При обновлении страницы перехожу сразу на неё.

Есть страница `/#training_25`, созданная Аяксом. При обновлении страницы ничего не происходит.

Создавал страницу по окончанию работы Ajax:

```
$( '#training_'+training_id ).page({
 create: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Классы jquery обновляются, а переход по хешу не срабатывает.